# Multivariable Limits Using Substitution

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Suppose  I want to calculate a multivariable limit using substitution. For example,
$$
\lim _{(x,y)\to (0,0) } \frac{2^{xy}-1}{xy}
$$
or 
$$
\lim _{(x,y)\to (0,0) } \frac{\sin(xy) }{xy}.
$$
Substituting $u=xy$ and then moving to a limit of $u\to 0$ gives a result. As far as I can understand, if the limit of $u\to 0 $ exists, then in particular, the above limits also exist (even though the case of $u\to 0$ can also correspond to e.g. $(x,y)\to(0,2) $).

I am not sure if this is legitimate and if I am right. Is it possible that the substitution $u=xy$ and then $u\to 0 $ only corresponds to a specific path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in both cases the substitution is legitimate since $u=xy\to 0$ for any path and we obtain

$$\lim _{(x,y)\to (0,0) } \frac{2^{xy}-1}{xy}=\lim _{u\to 0 } \frac{2^{u}-1}{u}$$

and

$$\lim _{(x,y)\to (0,0) } \frac{\sin(xy) }{xy}=\lim _{u\to 0 } \frac{\sin u }{u}$$

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PseudoMath You are welcome! Bye